# React Native Audit - what is the right course of action here, the audit fix is not working

Tags: react-native, macos, npm

While installing a few packages with NPM I got this error and now I am trying to make it clean. What is the right course of action here. I already tried the adult fix and it does not help.

```
# npm audit report

json5  <1.0.2
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in JSON5 via Parse Method - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9c47-m6qq-7p4h
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@46.0.21, which is a breaking change
node_modules/find-babel-config/node_modules/json5
  find-babel-config  <=1.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of json5
  node_modules/find-babel-config
    babel-plugin-module-resolver  2.3.0 - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of find-babel-config
    node_modules/babel-plugin-module-resolver
      babel-preset-expo  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-module-resolver
      node_modules/babel-preset-expo
        expo  >=14.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-preset-expo
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-asset
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-constants
        node_modules/expo
          @react-native-google-signin/google-signin  >=9.0.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of expo
          node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin

xml2js  <0.5.0
Severity: moderate
xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution  - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-776f-qx25-q3cc
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@46.0.21, which is a breaking change
node_modules/xml2js
  @expo/config-plugins  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
  node_modules/@expo/config-plugins
    @expo/cli  >=0.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/dev-server
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/metro-config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/prebuild-config
    node_modules/@expo/cli
    @expo/config  >=3.3.23-alpha.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
    node_modules/@expo/config
      @expo/metro-config  >=0.1.49-alpha.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
      node_modules/@expo/metro-config
        @expo/dev-server  >=0.1.49-alpha.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/metro-config
        node_modules/@expo/dev-server
      expo-constants  >=10.1.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
      node_modules/expo-constants
        expo-asset  >=8.6.1
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expo-constants
        node_modules/expo-asset
    @expo/prebuild-config  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/config-plugins
    Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
    node_modules/@expo/prebuild-config

15 vulnerabilities (10 moderate, 5 high)
```

As I mentioned earlier, I tried  npm audit fix and  npm audit fix --force and nothing really helped.